# Styling custom base class in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance, styles, abstract-class

I want to style four classes which are inherited from an abstract base class. Each of these classes have the same style. So I'm trying to style all classes at once. But Wpf does not allow me to assign an abstract base class to `TargetType` property of `Style`. Is it possible to do this or do I have to style each class one by one?

Comment: Why do you want to style a class ? You should only use stylings in xaml, and here you can define an own style and use it as a static resource

Comment: I'm doing this in xaml. But I think abstract classes are not acceptable for TargetType property. It only suggests me concrete classes

Comment: They are not acceptable because designer uses `Relfection` or Shadow Copy of an object to resolve Binding and produce the `IntelliSense` for you. If you want to have that functionality I would change the type of the base class by removing `abstract`. This way it will work for you.

Comment: @YektaMirkan, please show definition of your abstract class. I don't think `abstract` is a limitation